# How to auto scroll down ListView in Xamarin.forms (MVVM design pattern)

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am developed an chat application with Xamarin.Forms (MVVM Design pattern).
I need to scroll down the ListView (List of chat messages) automatically after sending a message.

My View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         ...>


<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource MainLayoutStyle}">

        ...

        <Frame
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            CornerRadius="5"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Padding="5">
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>

                    <ListView
                        x:Name="MainScreenMessagesListView"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        BackgroundColor="#e5ddd5"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
                    </ListView>

                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Frame>

        ...

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I cant use ScrollTo method because of my design pattern (am i right?)
and there no ScrollTo property in xaml.

So what the solution for this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way of solving this is by using the [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/).

From your PageModel send a signal, i.e.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object> (this, "MessageReceived");
```

Then in your code-behind of your Page, you can subscribe to it and scroll down or do whatever.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object> (this, "MessageReceived", (sender) => {
    MainScreenMessagesListView.ScrollTo(..., ScrollToPosition.End, true);
});
```

Instead of the dots you will have to determine the last item as an object in your `ListView`. You can do this two ways, either determine it in the page by casting the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView`. But maybe it is better to supply it as a parameter with the MessagingCenter call.

In your PageModel you could change it to this: `MessagingCenter.Send<object, object> (this, "MessageReceived", lastReceivedMessage);`

And retrieve the value like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object> (this, "MessageReceived", (sender, arg) => {
    MainScreenMessagesListView.ScrollTo(arg, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you but what i need to put instead of "????"
MainScreenMessagesListView.ScrollTo(?????, ScrollToPosition.End, true);

Comment: Thank you!
Its not working..Im in Debug mode and i put Break point at this line: 
MainScreenMessagesListView.ScrollTo(...)
And the application not stop there.

I send the signal in the end of my viewModel constructor

Comment: Forget it..I removed the sending of the signal from the constructor. I put it in my onMessage function. and i got this exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Im working on it. if you have an idea i will be more than happy

Comment: InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ViewModels.ChatViewModel(Navigation);

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "MessageReceived", (sender, arg) => {
                try
                {
                    MainScreenMessagesListView.ScrollTo(arg, ScrollToPosition.End, true); // arg == 0
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    int size = MainScreenMessagesListView.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count(); // size == 1
                }
            });

OutOfRange exception - why?

Comment: Notice how I did a -1 in my example code. The count gives you the total objects, the ListView, will start counting at 0.

Comment: Same problem...still go to catch with out of range exception

Comment: And what does that Exception say?

Comment: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\nParameter name: index"

Comment: Please carefully debug through it and compare the lengths of the collections with each other. There must be some -1 missing somewhere. It's kind of hard to say without all the code and be able to walk through it.

Comment: I am debugging for a 1 hour without success...what am i missed? Please see the debug status and the watch variables: https://ibb.co/iX8r45

Comment: Just for be sure - I need to keep "object" as is yes? i dont need to replace this type to my viewmodel type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152628/discussion-between-gerald-versluis-and-matan-marciano).

Comment: The solution is not for MVVM patern

Comment: Why do you reckon it's not?

Comment: it's not fully mvvm pattern, isn't it?

Comment: @Behzad I reckon it's the closest you can get as unless you do custom renderer, there is no way you can access the UI control in ViewModel.